# Fixing the broken .exe lin by associating the .exe to execfile prevents app from launching

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, file-association

Recently I started running into this issue that when I tried to open OneNote/Excel/PowerPoint, the `.exe` file would open up in Notepad.

I tried a bunch of things to solve this issue. A combination of the following yielded the result that now those apps don't open in Notepad but when I click to open them, it starts to open (as indicated by the small blue buffer sign) but never really opens:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-unable-to-open-exe-lnk-files-windows-7

I downloaded the `.exe` file and the `.lnk` file, and merged it as was suggested. That did not work. The link was still broken, and the .exe files still opened in notepad. Then I set `assoc.exe=exefile` in cmd prompt. Now, I am not sure if the association problem is fixed, because while the .exe file does not open in Notepad anymore, the app does not launch at all.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to the community. To prevent _"Try this" "I already tried"_ - comment threads you should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768552/edit) your question and actually list what you've tried and with what results. Best is that instead of "this doesn't work" you write "when I do this, happens that" as those can give hints on what's failing. Please check [how to write a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help to get a handle on how to write clear, focused questions that are easy to answer. Also best to edit the question again if clarifications are asked.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Fixed!

Comment: I was actually referring to "I tried a bunch of things" :-) As nobody knows what's already been tried this often results in extended _"Try this" "Already tried"_ -commend threads, from which it's darn difficult to dig out relevant info.